# Fire an event when a TextField text property is set

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a `TextField` instance on stage. The copy within the field is updated from outside my project by a 3rd party system that I have no access to. I don't know exactly how this is achieved but I need to know when it has happened.

I want a way of telling when the text is updated within the field so I can then format and position the field based on its new content. I've tried

```
myTextField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, updateMethod);
```

but it seems that this only fires when the text is changed by direct user interaction and not the kind of injection from outside that I am getting.

Is there any way that I can listen for an assignment to `myTextField.text` rather that only for changes made by the user via mouse/keyboard?

Appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly accessing the text field, you can wrap it with your own class, and dispatch events when the setter is fired: (untested code)

```
public class MyTextField extends EventDispatcher {

    private var textField:TextField;

    public MyTextField(t:TextField) {
        textField = t;
    }

    public function set text(s:String) {
        textField.text = s;
        var e:Event = new Event(Event.CHANGE);
        dispatchEvent(e);
    }

    public function get text():String {
        return textField.text;
    }

}
```

And else where in your code:

```
var mytf:MyTextField = new MyTextField(stage.myTextField); //stage.myTextField is the reference to the text field on the stage

mytf.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, function(e:Event) { /* get event */ });

// don't use stage.myTextField.text to set text, instead, use:
mytf.text = "setting text!"; //this will trigger the event callback above
```

Comment: That would be a nice solution and I will try messing around with it but my problem is that the value is set by an external system (Mediamind Mass Versioning if it means anything to anyone). This scans the file for TextField instances and exposes them to external content. So, I don't have the option of targeting a custom class.

Comment: Hm. In that case it may also be useful to look into listening from events directly from the external system, and updating your flash from that (may have to use js/ExternalInterface, however)

Comment: Would also be worth mentioning that the class can extend TextField instead, override the accessors and/or mutators, and then determine how to handle the events. This way you skip having to create the textfield object inside the class.